# Swift - Popup Dialog disable orientation

Tags: swift, popup, orientation, landscape, portrait

i am currently working with Swift Popup library from:

https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Everythink works fine despite one thing. When the orientation changes, the popupdialog rotates... This fact conflicts with my implementation:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.setTabBarVisible(visible: false, animated: true)
}
```

How can i disable orientation switch in popupdialog?

I have researched their github repo and various posts but no hint...

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try by making your app orientation to Portrait only..